# How to put array of objects into new Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have several drop down lists on my page. Based on the selection of these drop downs, I would like to build resulting Json object that looks like this:

```
{"list":{"city":["1","2","3"],"businessName":["City1","AnotherCity"]}}
```

Dropdowns event here:

```
    $(".chosen-select").each(function () {
        $id = this.id;
        $value = $(this).val();
    });
```

Of course I would like this to be as generic as possible therefore I'm getting $id (which in my case is "city" and "businessName", however it may be different on another page.

```
$value = $(this).val();
```

is of course array of selected values ie: "["1","2","3"];

I've tried this but it's not what I want

```
    var jsonObj = {
         list: []
    };

    $(".chosen-select").each(function () {
        $id = this.id;
        $value = $(this).val();

        var obj = {};
        obj[$id] = $value;
        jsonObj.list.push(obj);
    });
```

which results in this:

```
{"list":[{"city":["2","3"]},{"businessName":["KrakVenue1","KrakVenue3"]}]}
```

and NOT what I want.

How would I do it?
thanks

Comment: add a fiddle that will make it better.

Comment: Just a side note: we normally try to reserve the `$` symbol for variables that are `jQuery` collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want your list to be an object, do not create it as an array.

```
var jsonObj = {
     list: {}
};

$(".chosen-select").each(function () {
    var id = this.id,
        value = $(this).val();

    jsonObj.list[id] = value;
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4f43Q/

Comment: exactly what I wanted. thanks. will accept in 5 min.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonObj.list` should be the object you want and not an array, so you shouldn't push to it.

```
if (!jsonObj.list.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    jsonObj.list[id] = value;
}
else {
    // key already exists.  What should you do with it?
    // if `value` is another array, you can use `.concat`
}
```

It seems like `value` should be an array, but they are individual values and you want to treat them as an array, use:

```
if (!jsonObj.list.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    jsonObj.list[id] = [];
}
jsonObj.list[id].push(value);
```

Comment: assuming from the selector `.chosen-select` that it is a `<select>` element with `multiple` attribute, the `.val()` returns an array of selected options.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli never assume anything!

Comment: @ExplosionPills fair point, but in this case the use of `.val()` and the fact that he gets results as an array (*he posted what he gets*) make that a non-issue.